# show map as a widget in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-widget

i want to show live google map as a home widget over android screen , but the problem is android only allows following views to get displayed. and i want to make use of webview.

- AnalogClock
- Button
- Chronometer
- ImageButton
- ImageView
- ProgressBar
- TextView

So does any have another alternatives or some tricky solution to make the map appear as an widget

Comment: What sort of map, does it need to be updated? Could you get away with using ImageButton as a thumbnail of the map which links to Maps or your application with the full feature?

Comment: i want to show a live googe map in a small view and i guess ImageButton will only display the static image

Answer (score 0):

well, MapView extends View class, so you could try to create Bitmap from it, by calling getDrawingCache() metod.

but then again, I think that's against Google's TOS.

Comment: But every time i need to get the bitmap and set it on a image button right ? and i am not using MapView , i am using WebView in which i am loading map

Comment: How the Google Map can set itself as a live wallpaper in android ?